# Insert values to php multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

How can I insert values into a multidimensional array in php? I need to add more and more rows to array using a while loop.

Here is my code:

```
$size=10;
$p=0;
while($p<$size)
{
    $myarray = array(
        array("number"=>$data[$p],"data"=>$kkk[1],"status"=>"A"),
        array("number"=>$data[$p],"data"=>$kkk[1],"status"=>"A"));
    // Each time the loop executes, I need to add more array to myarray.
    $p++;
}
```

Comment: You will need something like a `for($i=0;$<=$p:$i++)` loop inside your `while` loop.

Comment: try ``$myarray[] = array( ... );``. Might need to initialize ``$myarray = array();`` outside of the loop, beforehand.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$size = 10;
$p = 0;
$myarray = array();
while($p < $size) {
  $myarray[] = array("number" => $data[$p], "data" => $kkk[1], "status" => "A");
  $p++;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$my_array = array()
foreach (range($p, $size-1) as $key) {
    array_push($my_array, array(
        "number" => $data[$key], 
        "data" => $kkk[1], 
        "status" => "A",
    ));
}
```

Comment: Why is a `foreach` necessary here? The `while` loop would work just fine.

Comment: `while` does not work with `range`, as far as I understand it. This is only another way to do the task, more elegant, IMHO :)

Comment: Why do you need `range()` though?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Is there a problem with `range` ?

Comment: There isn't a problem, but I don't think that's necessary here, TBH.

Answer (score -1):

```
$arr = new Array();
while($p<$size){
$arr[$p]["number"] = $data[$p];
$arr[$p]["data"] = $kkk[1];
$arr[$p]["status"] = "A";

$p++;
}
```