# Insert array inside a array at the end properly

Tags: php, arrays, insert

I have an array like this:

```
$itemID = [ 
    "appid" => 570,
    "contextid" => "2",
    "amount" => 1,
    "assetid" => $value 
];
```

I want to make another array which contains different `$itemID`s because `$value` will keep changing.

I'm trying to use `array_push` like this:

```
 $itemsID = [ ]; 

    array_push($itemsID, $itemID);
```

the output is:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [appid] => 570
        [contextid] => 2
        [amount] => 1
        [assetid] => 5628263595
    )

 )

Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [appid] => 570
        [contextid] => 2
        [amount] => 1
        [assetid] => 3651140937
    )

 )
```

I want the output to be:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [appid] => 570
        [contextid] => 2
        [amount] => 1
        [assetid] => 5628263595
[1] => Array
    (
        [appid] => 570
        [contextid] => 2
        [amount] => 1
        [assetid] => 3651140937
    )
```

how can I achieve this?

full code:

```
foreach ($select as $key => $value) {
 if(array_key_exists($key, $select)) {

    $itemID = [ "appid" => 570,
    "contextid" => "2",
    "amount" => 1,
    "assetid" => $value ];

    $itemsID = [ ]; 

    array_push($itemsID, $itemID);

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($itemsID);
    echo "</pre>";
 }
```

}

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert values to php multidimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19099091/insert-values-to-php-multidimensional-array)

Comment: I think the problem here is that you set $itemsId=[] just before the push, can you please show us your full code?

Comment: As i said the problem is that you always set to empty $itemsID with the portion of code $itemsID = []; delete it and initialize it at before the loop

Answer (score 2):

You are recreating `$itemsID` every iteration. Instead create it once outside the loop, add to it within the llop, and check it after the loop:

```
$itemList = [ ];
foreach ($select as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $select)) {

        $item = [ "appid" => 570,
                    "contextid" => "2",
                    "amount" => 1,
                    "assetid" => $value ];
        array_push($itemList, $item);
    }
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($itemList);
echo "</pre>";
```

Note i renamed your variables to `$item` and `$itemList` to better describe their usage - ambiguous variable names make code hard to follow

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php

```
$itemID = [ "appid" => 570,
    "contextid" => "2",
    "amount" => 1,
    "assetid" => $value ];

$itemID2 = [ "appid" => 570,
    "contextid" => "2",
    "amount" => 1,
    "assetid" => $value ];

$result = array_merge($itemID, $itemID2);
print_r($result);
```

Did not tested, but you get the idea.
Edited to your code:

```
    $itemsID = array();
    foreach ($select as $key => $value) {
         if(array_key_exists($key, $select)) {

            $itemID = [ "appid" => 570,
            "contextid" => "2",
            "amount" => 1,
            "assetid" => $value ];

            $itemsID[] = array_merge($itemsID, $itemID);

            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($itemsID);
            echo "</pre>";
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

With this line  `$itemsID = [ ];` you are adding another level of arrays to your main array. Without that line the code will do as you want.

Also a simpler syntax to add a new occurance to an array is just simply to do `$itemsID[] = $itemID;`

```
$itemsID = []; // create the array to hold result

foreach ($select as $key => $value) {
    if(array_key_exists($key, $select)) {

        $itemID = [ "appid" => 570,
                    "contextid" => "2",
                    "amount" => 1,
                    "assetid" => $value ];

        //  add another occurance to the array    
        // containing the new $itemID array
        $itemsID[] = $itemID; 
    }
}
// print the results
echo "<pre>";
print_r($itemsID);
echo "</pre>";
```